# Error when trying to insert an element to gcloud DB on App Engine with Dart

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

I am making a variation of the [Client Server Example](https://www.dartlang.org/cloud/client-server/) that just returns JSON strings using the Redstone framework. It has 3 routes:

- `/`    => get the whole list or names
- `/add/name`  => add "name" to the list and gets the list
- `/remove/name` => removes "name" from the list and gets the list

When I test locally everything works fine, however, when I deploy to App Engine I get an error when trying to add an element to the gcloud db. The error is

> Exception: Tried to insert 1 entities, but response seems to indicate
>   we inserted 0 entities.
>   package:appengine/src/api_impl/raw_datastore_v3_impl.dart 416:11 
>   DatastoreV3RpcImpl.commit.  dart:isolate
>   _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage

You can test the error live at this URL http://web3.arista-dev.appspot.com/add/my-name

Remove doesn't seem to work either but yields no error. Here is my code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart' as shelf;
import 'package:redstone/server.dart' as app;

import 'package:restonetest/model.dart';

import 'package:gcloud/db.dart';
import 'package:appengine/appengine.dart';

Key get itemsRoot => context.services.db.emptyKey.append (ItemRoot, id: 1);

DatastoreDB db = context.services.db;

Future<List<Item>> queryItems ()
{
    var query = context.services.db.query (Item, ancestorKey: itemsRoot)
        ..order ('name');

    return query.run ().toList ();
}

Future<List<Item>> addItemToDB (Item item)
{
    return db.query(Item, ancestorKey: itemsRoot).run()

        .any((i) => i.name == item.name)

        .then((exists) 
        {
                return ! exists ? db.commit(inserts: [item]) : false;
        });
}

@app.Route("/")
helloWorld() => queryItems();

@app.Route('/add/:name')
addItem (String name)
{
    return addItemToDB (new Item.create (name, itemsRoot)).then ((_) 
    {
        print (name);    
        return helloWorld();
    });
}

@app.Route('/delete/:name')
deleteItem (String name) 
{
    var query = db.query (Item, ancestorKey: itemsRoot)..filter('name =', name);

    return query.run().toList().then((list) 
    { 
        var toDelete = list.map((i) => i.key).toList();
        return db.commit(deletes: toDelete);
    })

    .then((_) => helloWorld());
}

main() {
    app.setupConsoleLog();
    app.setUp();
    runAppEngine(app.handleRequest);
    //app.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, package:appengine only allows one to call API services **inside a request handler**:

Each request handler invocation will get a new set of services. This allows package:appengine to give each request handler e.g. a different logging service instance. This allows all logging API calls to be grouped by request.

The way this is achieved in dart / package:appengine is by using **Zones**. For every incoming request, package:appengine makes a new Zone with API services and calls the request handler inside that. The handler can then use *'context.services.'* to make API calls.

So the issue in the program posted above, is that the DatastoreDB service **gets cached** from the first request (global fields are lazily initialized) and may no longer work for subsequent requests.

Changing

```dart
DatastoreDB db = context.services.db;
```

to

```dart
DatastoreDB get db => context.services.db;
```

should fix the problem, since the services object will be re-fetched every time from the request handler Zone.

This being said:

a) The error is swallowed reported is misleading and will be fixed in package:appengine

b) In the near future, we will allow background tasks / tasks making API calls outside of a request handler. This is missing at the moment, but will be implemented.

I hope this helps.